# Range Construction Pattern

Tags: range, d, higher-order-functions, construction

Given the following code

```
import std.datetime: Clock, SysTime, Duration;
SysTime[] times;
const n = 3;
foreach (i; 0..n) times ~= Clock.currTime;
```

is there a simpler, perhaps functional, higher order pattern with 
which to achieve the same goal?

A bonus would to be, when possible, minimize copyings of the elements perhaps through some in-place construction pattern.

See also: http://forum.dlang.org/thread/yofbijaejfyftpcjdcvd@forum.dlang.org#post-yofbijaejfyftpcjdcvd:40forum.dlang.org

**Update**:

Ok here's my try so far:

```
enum arityMin0(alias fun) = __traits(compiles, fun());

auto apply(alias fun, N)(N n) if (isCallable!fun &&
                                  arityMin0!fun &&
                                  !is(ReturnType!fun == void) &&
                                  isIntegral!N)
{
    import std.range: iota, map;
    return n.iota.map!(n => fun);
}
```

called as, for instance,

```
import std.datetime: Clock;
auto times = 3.apply!(Clock.currTime).array;
```

One detail left. The restriction

```
arity!fun == 0
```

evaluate to `false` in

```
auto times = 3.apply!(Clock.currTime).array;
```

because arity is actually either 0 and 1 here.

So `arity!fun` evaluates to `1` in this case because `Clock.currTime` takes a defaulted argument.

Maybe we need `arityMin` and `arityMax` in `std.traits` aswell.

In that case should I use `__traits(compiles` to implement `arityMin`?

Comment: Yes. It's better to test for capability rather than attributes. That way, your code will be more generic, and will work with e.g. functors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Evaluating `currTime` thrice:

```
auto times = 3.iota.map!(n => Clock.currTime).array();
```

Evaluating `currTime` once:

```
auto times = Clock.currTime.repeat(3).array();
```

Comment: Ok. Great. See follow up question above.